# angular dist folder does not contain index.html

Tags: angular, nginx, npm

I created a sample angular application using

```
ng new umm-client-app
```

It runs when I run it using:

```
ng serve -o
```

However when I build it using

```
npm build
```

it generates a pretty useless output:

[image]

where dist folder doesn't even have index.html in it.
When I copy this strange folder 'as is' into nginx (/usr/share/nginx/html) it doesn't serve it and gives me 403 (rightly so in my vew).
What am I missing? Where is that dist that can be shipped to the server/container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the new application builder that creates a `browser` directory and a `server` directory if you enable Prerendering or SSR.

Just copy the content of your `dist/browser`.